# ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent)

Tags: android

I'm getting this error **ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2585** when i start an intent

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

TextView lblName;
TextView lblyest;
TextView lbltoday;
TextView lblHigh;
TextView lblLow;
TextView lblChange;
TextView lblPcchange;

String name,yesterday,today,high,low,change,pcchange;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);



      lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
         lblyest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yesterday);
         lbltoday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.today);
         lblHigh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.high);
         lblLow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.low);
         lblChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.change);
         lblPcchange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pcchange);  

         Intent in = getIntent();
         name = in.getStringExtra("name");;
         yesterday = in.getStringExtra("yesterday");
         today =in.getStringExtra("today");
         high =in.getStringExtra("high");
         low = in.getStringExtra("low");
         change = in.getStringExtra("change");
         pcchange =in.getStringExtra("pcchange");


      //Error doesnt happen when the lines below are commented
        lblName.setText((CharSequence)name.toString());
        lblyest.setText(yesterday.toString());
        lbltoday.setText(today.toString());
        lblHigh.setText(high.toString());
        lblLow.setText(low.toString());
        lblChange.setText(change.toString());
        lblPcchange.setText(pcchange.toString());  

}
```

}

I know the error is triggered when i do the settext() function but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Put a full log-cat error

Answer (score 1):

You're setting variables, lblName and all those, to contain all of the child View's ... but you're doing it at the class level. Those Views are not created until the layout is inflated, in the line that reads 
`setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);`

, so all those variables are getting set to null.

Set the variables after your setContentView() call and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

    TextView lblName;
    TextView lblyest;
    TextView lbltoday;
    TextView lblHigh;
    TextView lblLow;
    TextView lblChange;
    TextView lblPcchange;

    String name, yesterday, today, high, low, change, pcchange;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.single_list_item );
        Intent in = getIntent();

        name = in.getStringExtra( "name" );
        ;
        yesterday = in.getStringExtra( "yesterday" );
        today = in.getStringExtra( "today" );
        high = in.getStringExtra( "high" );
        low = in.getStringExtra( "low" );
        change = in.getStringExtra( "change" );
        pcchange = in.getStringExtra( "pcchange" );

        lblName = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.name );
        lblyest = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.yesterday );
        lbltoday = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.today );
        lblHigh = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.high );
        lblLow = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.low );
        lblChange = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.change );
        lblPcchange = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.pcchange );

        lblName.setText( (CharSequence) name.toString() );
      /*  lblyest.setText(yesterday.toString());
        lbltoday.setText(today.toString());
        lblHigh.setText(high.toString());
        lblLow.setText(low.toString());
        lblChange.setText(change.toString());
        lblPcchange.setText(pcchange.toString());  */

    }


}
```

Actually, You can not initialize views before setContentView() call. That's why, you are getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

move these lines after `setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);`

```
TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
TextView lblyest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yesterday);
TextView lbltoday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.today);
TextView lblHigh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.high);
TextView lblLow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.low);
TextView lblChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.change);
TextView lblPcchange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pcchange);
```